# PHP IntlDateFormatter::format returns empty value for timezone

Tags: php, intl

This code works as expected on my test machine but fails on production. Not sure what's wrong with the setup, the only difference is ICU version I guess.

```
<?php
$timeZone = 'Asia/Shanghai';
date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);
echo date("c") . "\n";
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('en', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, $timeZone, NULL, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx");
echo $formatter->format(time()) . "\n";
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('en', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, $timeZone, NULL, "V X x v O Z z");
echo $formatter->format(time()) . "\n";
```

Expected output (test setup, PHP 5.6.25, intl version 1.1.0, ICU version 56.1, ICU Data version 56.1):

```
2016-09-10T12:42:30+08:00
2016-09-10T12:42:30+08:00
cnsha +08 +08 China Time GMT+8 +0800 GMT+8
```

Actual output (production, PHP 5.6.25, intl version 1.1.0, ICU version 50.1.2
ICU Data version 50.1):

```
2016-09-10T12:43:22+08:00
2016-09-10T12:43:22
GMT+08:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was ICU version. Updating to 57.0 fixed the problem